# In my Dockerfile, how do I use the `COPY --from` syntax to use images from Google Container Registry?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I'm using Google Kubernetes Engine, Cloud Build, and Image Registry. [According to the kubectl docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-an-external-image-as-a-stage), I can use external images in Dockerfiles with `COPY --from`. This would be very useful because when I run `gcloud builds submit` on my Dockerfile, I'd like to add in images already built on GCR instead of rebuilding everything in one Dockerfile.

I've tried adding lines like `COPY --from=quickstart-image:latest /some/path/thing.conf /thing.conf` but I always get

`pull access denied for quickstart-image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'`

Is there some authentication step I'm missing? How can I get this to work?

Comment: What does the full content of your `Dockerfile` contain?  For access, it might be that you need to run the recipe described here ... https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/configure-docker

Comment: Other than the `COPY --from` line, it contains another stage with few typical commands like `RUN /usr/local/bin/install_node '>=8.12.0'` that generate no errors on their own. Should I post the entire file here? Running that recipe tells me `gcloud credential helpers already registered correctly.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `quickstart-image` refers to [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) which, as error message suggests, it is not existing in Docker Hub.

If you want to use an image from GCR, you have to use full address like `asia.gcr.io/project-name/repo-name`.